# Send SAML assertion from IDP as acookie

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to  use WSO2 Identity Server as an IDP but partner would like the assertion to be returned as a cookie.  Is this possible with WSO2 ID Server?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to the SAML2 SSO web browser specification, IDP (WSO2IS) return SAML response as HTTP POST (body). if you want to return it as a cookie from WSOIS (It means assertion in the HTTP Header),  it is not possible with default behavior.  IMO, there may be work around that can be done...  One is that, we can register a new servlet with WSO2IS (custom servlet).  Then WSO2IS do post the SAML response to that custom servlet.  Inside custom servlet, we can extract the SAML response from post request. And then SAML assertion can be extracted from response and we can add this assertion in to HTTP header using the custom servlet.  Finally, WSO2IS would return a SAML assertion in HTTP header... likewise we can customize the default behavior easily.  However, could you, please elaborate what is the actual use case?

Comment: I think we have found a better solution.  Thanks for info, may be useful in the future